# Looping through nested arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have an array of objects `userEvents` that I want to use the `event` array inside of the object. The `event` array is storing objects as well, in which I am trying to access the `start` property and change it. I was thinking about nesting map functions, but I have had no success. I attached the console log of array of userEvents  [image]

```
const { events } = this.props.events;
    const userEvents = events
```

Comment: please add the data in text form to the question. please have a look, too: [mcve]

Comment: FYI you can shorten your current code to `const { events: userEvents } = this.props.events`

Comment: @Li357 How would I shorten it further by taking the events array inside userEvents?

Answer (score 1):

Giving you just want

> access `start` property

```
userEvents.forEach(userEvent => userEvent.events
  .forEach(event => { console.log(event.start) })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array that basically simplifies to this:

```
let userEvents = [
  {events: [{start: 1},{start: 2}]},
  {events: [{start: 3},{start: 4}]}
]
```

You should be able to loop through `userEvents`, then inside that, look at each element's `events` array and loop through that:

```js
let userEvents = [
  {events: [{start: 1},{start: 2}]},
  {events: [{start: 3},{start: 4}]}
]

userEvents.forEach(e => {
  e.events.forEach(event =>{
    console.log(event.start)
  })
})
```

This will get you access to the elements you want. If you are trying to extract these or turn them into a different data format, of course tools like `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduces()` will be helpful.

For example, getting all your starts as an array:

```js
let userEvents = [
  {events: [{start: 1},{start: 2}]},
  {events: [{start: 3},{start: 4}]}
]

let starts = userEvents.reduce((a, e) => {
  return [...a, ...e.events.map(event => event.start)]
}, [])
console.log(starts)
```